How to redirect an old domain to a new one in Next.js (Vercel deployment)?
I have two domains properly configured in my Vercel project: an old one and a new one. I would like to redirect the old domain to the new one. In my next.config.mjs file, I have set up a redirect function that outputs the following:
[
  {
    "source": "/:path*",
    "destination": "https://newdomain.com/:path*",
    "permanent": true,
    "has": [
      {
        "type": "host",
        "value": "olddomain.com"
      },
      {
        "type": "host",
        "value": "www.olddomain.com"
      }
    ]
  }
]

However, the redirection is not working as expected. Am I missing something, or is there another way to correctly set up the domain redirection in Vercel using Next.js?
Any help would be appreciated!

A few thoughts: 1. Have you confirmed that both old domains have CNAME records pointing to the vercel project? 2. Have you tried making two separate redirect entries (one where host is olddomain.com and the other where it is www.olddomain.com)?
